# Returning Iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, auto

Using map.find() or any function that returns an iterator.
Is there any benefit to storing the returned value as a ref ?

```
const auto  it  = map.find(0);
const auto& it2 = map.find(0);
```

Comment: I doubt you'll see any performance difference.  Such micro optimizations should not be considered until you've actually profiled the code and determined the performance is not acceptable.

Comment: The compiler will likely generate the exact same code for those two cases, once you enable the optimizer. Don't do micro optimizations like that without using a profiler (on optimized code) to prove that it actually makes a difference.

Comment: Storing references to temporary objects is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @SidS in this case it is just fine

Answer (score 1):

`const auto&` could be helpful if you were using it in a range `for` loop, where you are also sure about the lifetime:

```
for(const auto& it : map)
{....}
```

And as @[Ted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo) pointed out also this form of `for` loop

```
for(const auto& [key, value] : the_map) 
 { ... }
```

Otherwise the microptimization (if there is any)doesn't worth the potential bugs it brings.
Maybe someday another programmer remove the `const` then you have a reference to a temporary.

Comment: or even `for(const auto& [key, value] : the_map) { ... }`

Comment: "someday another programmer remove the const then you have a reference to a temporary" this will not work unless you have pesky MS compiler.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 moments that make this method useless:

1. iterators designed as lightweight objects that cheap to pass and store by value.
2. even if you would have heavy object in this case it will not save anything. Here is why.

Imagine this code:

```
HeavyObject foobar();

auto obj1 = foobar();
const auto &obj2 = foobar();
```

in early age of C++ second case will be more optimal due to copy ctor possibly called in the first one. This is not the case anymore due to RVO (return value optimization) which is mandatory since C++17. So your code used to make sense for more complex objects than iterators. In case of iterator it was very unlikely you would see any difference in performance even without optimization enabled and even when RVO was not mandated. So such code could be considered fine by some people but I would find it unreadable as iterators usually passed around by value and such code at least will raise a question, why author did this?